# Define global variable instead of to include it in function parameter Python

Tags: python, function, subprocess

To solve my previous question, I decided to change the script and assign a global variable at the beginning.

(modification in the script)

```
inDir = sys.argv[1]

if inDir.endswith("/"):
    outDir = ("/".join(inDir.split("/")[:-2])) + "/" + (inDir.split("/")[-2]) + "_cv"
else:
    outDir = ("/".join(inDir.split("/")[:-1])) + "/" + (inDir.split("/")[-1]) + "_cv"
```

Old script

```
def check_outDir(indir):
    if inDir.endswith("/"):
        outDir = ("/".join(indir.split("/")[:-2])) + "/" + (indir.split("/")[-2]) + "_cv"
        if not os.path.exists(outDir):
            try:
                os.makedirs(outDir)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                    raise
        return outDir

    else:
        outDir = ("/".join(indir.split("/")[:-1])) + "/" + (indir.split("/")[-1]) + "_cv"
        if not os.path.exists(outDir):
            try:
                os.makedirs(outDir)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                    raise
        return outDir


def run_CVTree(str_n):
    subprocess.call("cv", "-I", inDir, "-i", "list_CVTree.txt", "-g", "fna", "-O", outDir)
```

I know that I can define the outDir at the beginning of the script but...

How can I do this without touche the second function?

Comment: I don't understand the question. As far as I can tell, you're asking how to call the `check_outDir` function and store its return value in a variable? Surely that can't really be your problem, can it?

Comment: Yes, to be used in another function.

Comment: So the question is how to define global variables?

Comment: maybe. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why can't you touch the second function? Globals are generally a Bad Idea™

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a more ugly way than defining the `outDir` as a global variable:

```
import inspect

def set_global_inside_function():
    inspect.currentframe().f_globals["a"] = "Wow"

def test():
    print(a)

set_global_inside_function()
test()
```

output: `Wow`

Comment: You're still defining `outDir` as a global variable, you just used uglier code to do it than `outDir = ...`

Comment: Sure, I said it "a more ugly way".

Comment: But it's still a global variable. What's the point of using ugly code to define a global variable?

Comment: That's ... Um... meaningless. But as you see, OP wants to use global variable but doesn't want to define it, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In python just like in other languages, there is scoping.

Any function has it's own local scope, and if you want to "share" a variable that located inside the function, you have 3 options:

1. Using `global`.
2. Returning the value, and assign it to varaible outside the function (**Best way for you**).
3. There is another option if you pass a mutable argument and change it inside the function, but that case a bit advanced.

As I said assign the returned value of the function `check_outDir` and pass it to `run_CVTree(path)` (you don't use `str_n` ...).

```
my_dir = check_outDir(path)
run_CVTree(path=my_dir)
```

And if your in for Clean Code, the name of the first function should be `create_dir_if_not_exists`,
Or `create_dir` and raise an exception if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable outside both functions and modify it inside the first one, and use in the second one.